# "where java" Not finding correct java.exe

Tags: java, windows

For some reason, the `where java` command (on windows) is not returning the location of my JDK.
My JDK is at `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-10.0.1\bin`
All the correct executables are there (like `java.exe`)

Whenever I do "where java" in the console, I get this:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath\javaw.exe
C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath\javaw.exe
```

With neither of them being the correct jdk location.

Any ideas? I can provide further information if needed.

Edit: Also, it does return the correct location, but only whenever the cmd prompt is inside the same folder as the java.exe. (Whenever its in `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-10.0.1\bin`)

Comment: Change your OS's path property

Comment: Wow. Thanks! It works. Just simply adding the JDK location to the Path environment variable fixed the problem.